# parsing html table using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am trying to fetch the table from below html with no success. Earlier I was using lxml but it failed after there were some changes in format of the text which is coming from a weblink. I don't know much about parsing. Thanks for any helps/pointers.

```
>>> text2='<html xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:user="http://mycompany.com/mynamespace" xmlns:filter="http://mycompany.com/myfilternamespace">\r\n  <head>\r\n    <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-16">\r\n    <title>\r\n    </title>\r\n  </head>\r\n  <body>\r\n    <table border="1">\r\n      <tr>\r\n        <td>\r\n\t\t\t\t\tCOBDate\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</td>\r\n        <td>TOTAL</td>\r\n      </tr>\r\n      <tr>\r\n  <td>2013-6-12</td>\r\n        <td>-10000000</td>\r\n      </tr>\r\n    </table>\r\n  </body>\r\n</html>'
>>> soup=BeautifulSoup(text2)
>>> soup.findAll('table')
[]
>>> BeautifulSoup(text2, 'html.parser').find_all('table')
[<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>

                    COBDate

                    </td>
<td>TOTAL</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2013-6-12</td>
<td>-10000000</td>
</tr>
</table>]
```

Though BeautifulSoup(text2, 'html.parser').find_all('table') returns a table, the same not happening for below text,

```
>>> text1='<html xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:user="http://mycompany.com/mynamespace" xmlns:filter="http://mycompany.com/myfilternamespace">\r\n  <head>\r\n    <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-16">\r\n    <title>\r\n    </title>\r\n  </head>\r\n  <body>\r\n    <table border="1">\r\n      <tr>\r\n        <td>\r\n\t\t\t\t\tCOBDate\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</td>\r\n        <td>TOTAL</td>\r\n      </tr>\r\n      <tr>\r\n        <td>2013-6-13</td>\r\n        <td>-1000000</td>\r\n      </tr>\r\n    </table>\r\n  </body>\r\n</html>'
>>> BeautifulSoup(text1, 'html.parser').find_all('table')
[]
>>> BeautifulSoup(text1).find_all('table')
[]
```

I have updated beautifulsoup, lxml and libxml2. Not sure what's the issue.

Comment: What version of BeautifulSoup is this? Your input works fine for me, on BeautifulSoup 4.3.2 (with lxml installed).

Comment: same. 4.3.2. I just tried encoding as it was not working without it anyway. I will edit it.

Comment: What does `BeautifulSoup(text2, 'html.parser').find_all('table')` give you? If you get a result, then your `lxml` installation is mucking things up.

Comment: yes, that gets me the table. Seems like I need to reinstall lxml. Thanks for help.

Comment: If `libxml2` is not statically linked into your lxml install (anywhere but Windows, usually), make sure you upgrade that too.

Comment: I updated all three of beautifulSoup,lxml and libxml2. Problem seems to be something else. Updated another text (text1) for which it doesn't work. Though I have found out another way using lxml which works but just not sure why bs won't work.

Comment: Well seems like the texts are not html. It's working for all of the texts using 'xml' as parser. This works: BeautifulSoup(text1, 'xml') for them.

Comment: Your text worked fine for me using the `lxml` parser (as well as `html.parser` and `html5lib`). I've not seen it directly, but here on SO did come across more people with similar problems where `lxml` would not build a perfectly parseable HTML tree. It *feels* like a version problem, but without more detail I cannot, of course, be sure.

Comment: Again, I have no problem using `beautiful(text).find('table')` for both examples. I took a look at the page itself and it is a simple HTML tree with two rows two columns.. the only thing you might want to pay attention to later is it is encoded in utf-16 where most cases pages are encoded by 'utf-8'. Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though this is less of an answer and more of a workaround the issue. From the comments above I understand this may be an issue with versions of the packages. I am posting the solution which is working for me, for in case someone facing or may face in future a similar issue. The first one which worked for me:

`from lxml import html`

`from bs4 import UnicodeDammit`

`doc = UnicodeDammit(text1, is_html=False)`

`parser = html.HTMLParser(encoding=doc.original_encoding)`

`root = html.document_fromstring(text1, parser=parser)`

`table = root.find('.//table')`

And the other one simply using BeautifulSoup:

`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`

`BeautifulSoup(text1, 'xml')`
or
`BeautifulSoup(text1, ['lxml','xml'])`